# PriceBookEntry.Name Equal to Text variable

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm trying to look for price book entries whose name equals a string obtained from a checkbox selection.

If I use a string literal in the value field of the comparison (i.e., actually write the text), it works. But if I get the text from a record (i.e., {!Record}), it tries to find the entry using the reference value of the record instead of the string it contains.

How can I "dereference" the string and use it for comparison?

Thank you

edit:
It's not a code snippet, because i'm doing it in Flow.
[image]

This is the message that I get. It is using the reference as text.
[image]

edit 2: The variable {!Loop_on_Selected_Cases} is a text variable. However, when using it as a comparison with the field "Name" of the PriceBookEntry object, "01t6800000..." gets compared instead of the actual string (which in this case is "Tire Service".

Comment: Can you add code snippets? It makes it easier to interpret what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit] your question to expand/expound on  what exactly is in the `{!Loop_on_Selected_Cases}` variable. Is it a complete Case object record? Is it a text variable? Or ??? Please help us to try to help you.

Comment: The variable {!Loop_on_Selected_Cases} is a text variable. However, when using it as a comparison with the field "Name" of the PriceBookEntry object, "01t6800000..." gets compared instead of the actual string (which in this case is "Tire Service".

Comment: You have to specify a field in the Current Item in Loop.  Right now it is comparing against the entire record, so the system defaults to the ID field, so that's why you're seeing the ID value.

Comment: The loop is iterating over a collection of strings, so isn't the current item supposed to be a string? There are no fields on the current item.